# mySQL Parse Error on Line 10

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a Login System for my Website.

I have tried/looked at a few videos to solve my problem but I am still unsure of what I am doing wrong.

For a better Look at my code please view this Link: http://prntscr.com/2jeye5

Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected '$myusername' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 10`

Line 10 starts with  `$myusername = $_POST['user'];` in the code listed below.

```
<?php
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle)

    $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password=$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
        echo 'It worked';
    }
?>
```

Comment: There's something missing on the preceding line. Look at it. -- Your SQL also lacks quotes around the second string value.

Comment: stripslashes() dose **not** sanitise db inputs. you shouldn't be using un hashed passwords

Comment: Do you have any form or first page where the user can input he's/her username and password before this page?

Comment: Please learn about [SQL injection defense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [proper password hashing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Answer (score 1):

Terminate line 8, and you're missing a single-quote before `$mypassword`.

Answer (score 1):

Missing semi colon

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle)
```

should be

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);
```

Since username and password are probably strings, it should be enclosed in quotes

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password=$mypassword'";
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

if(isset($POST['user']) && isset($POST['pass']))
{
  $myusername = stripslashes($POST['user']);
  $mypassword = stripslashes($POST['pass']);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($count==1){
   echo 'It worked';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not worked';
}
```